# Drawing a Path with multiple colors

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am drawing on android.graphics.Canvas using android.graphics.Path. I want to allow the user to draw using a range of colors and stroke widths, however, whenever the color or stroke width is changed, everything is re-drawn using the new color or stroke width. How can I fix this?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnW10"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Width10"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnW40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Width40"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnW70"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="Width70"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnBlue"
            android:text="Blue"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnRed"
            android:text="Red"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/btnGreen"
            android:text="Green"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.vladislav.canvaswc.DrawLine
        android:id="@+id/drwLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
   DrawLine dr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
        Button btnG=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
        Button btnR=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
        Button btnW10=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnW10);
        Button btnW40=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnW40);
        Button btnW70=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnW70);
        dr =(DrawLine) findViewById(R.id.drwLine);
        btnB.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnG.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnR.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnW10.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnW40.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnW70.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnBlue : dr.changeColor(Color.BLUE);break;
            case R.id.btnGreen : dr.changeColor(Color.GREEN);break;
            case R.id.btnRed : dr.changeColor(Color.RED);break;
            case R.id.btnW10 : dr.changeWidth(10f);break;
            case R.id.btnW40 : dr.changeWidth(40f);break;
            case R.id.btnW70 : dr.changeWidth(70f);break;
        }
    }
}
```

drawline.java   ChangeWidthColor its my interface with 2 methods changeColor() 
and changeWidth()

```
public class DrawLine extends View implements ChangeWidthColor {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public DrawLine(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);

    }

    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {

        //paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        //paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

    }

    @Override
    public void changeColor(int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);


    }

    @Override
    public void changeWidth(float width) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(width);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
       canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x= event.getX();
                y= event.getY();
                path.moveTo(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x= event.getX();
                y= event.getY();
                path.lineTo(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The entire Path is being redrawn with the new Paint on each click. One approach would be to maintain a list of Path and Paint objects which you would then iterate through onDraw.

Comment: @burntsugar 
You can tell me step by step how I can do, I'm new to android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution maintains a List of Path objects and a List of Integers for storing colors. These Lists are in parallel - 1 entry in each list for a Path and color pair. onDraw iterates these Lists, drawing each Path with the corresponding color.

Each time the user clicks to change the color, a new Path is created. ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE call moveTo(x,y) and lineTo(x,y) on the path, and ACTION_UP causes the Path and current color to be added to the lists.

Note: I have not implemented a solution for stroke width, however, you should be able to follow the example and add this yourself.

```
public class DrawLine extends View {

    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int currentColor = Color.BLACK;
    private List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private float x;
    private float y;

    public DrawLine(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        paint.setColor(currentColor);
    }

    public void changeColor(int color) {
        currentColor = color;
        path = new Path();
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        for (int x = 0; x < paths.size(); x++) {
            paint.setColor(colors.get(x));
            canvas.drawPath(paths.get(x), paint);
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                path.moveTo(x, y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                path.lineTo(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                paths.add(path);
                colors.add(currentColor);
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DrawLine extends View implements ChangeWidthColor {


    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private int currentColor = Color.BLACK;
    private float width = 1f;
    public float x;
    public float y;

    private LinkedList<Integer> color = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private LinkedList<Float> widthSize = new LinkedList<Float>();
    private LinkedList<Path> paths = new LinkedList<Path>();

    public DrawLine(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);


    }

    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public DrawLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        paint.setColor(currentColor);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

    }

    @Override
    public void changeColor(int color) {
        currentColor = color;
        path = new Path();


    }

    @Override
    public void changeWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;
        path = new Path();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(widthSize.get(i));
            paint.setColor(color.get(i));
            canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), paint);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                path.moveTo(x, y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                path.lineTo(x, y);
                invalidate();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                color.add(currentColor);
                paths.add(path);
                widthSize.add(width);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to call `invalidate()` inside your custom view whenever you are modifying something related to UI. so updated methods will be:

```
@Override
public void changeColor(int color) {
    paint.setColor(color);
    invalidate();

}

@Override
public void changeWidth(float width) {
    paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: if i draw line default color is black, i click button"blue" and my first and second line is blue. but first must be black(default) and second blue. Why 2 lines blue?